# magento not install using xampp 1.8.3 localhost on windows 7

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

hi when i install magento 1.8.0.0 i got these error at frontend

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1014873435

these error are shown at log files 1014873435

```
a:5:{i:0;s:239:"Error in file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\store.oxzin.com\app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\sql\adminnotification_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php"
- SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'adminnotification_inbox' already exists";i:1;s:1008:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\store.oxzin.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\store.oxzin.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.0')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\store.oxzin.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.0')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\store.oxzin.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\store.oxzin.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\store.oxzin.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\store.oxzin.com\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\store.oxzin.com\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:53:"/store.oxzin.com/index.php/install/wizard/configPost/";s:11:"script_name";s:26:"/store.oxzin.com/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

how can install magento without error.help

Comment: ok i have solved my problem. i had to remove all files and create new database. then i reinstall magento at starting and its working fine.thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem. i had to remove all files and create new database. then i reinstall magento at starting and its working fine. then run magento sample data query in new database and now everything is working fine. thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of XAMP, I would highly recommend that you install WAMP stack instead.
Download it from here: http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper

Get this version: Wampserver (32/64 bits & PHP 5.4) 2.4
Apache : 2.4.4 MySQL : 5.6.12 PHP : 5.4.16 PHPMyAdmin : 4.0.4 SqlBuddy : 1.3.3 XDebug : 2.2.3

Before you get this version, make sure your XAMP is uninstalled or turned off.
I recommend WAMP because it has the latest PHP and MySQL 5.6 (with innoDB storange engine magento 1.8 requires).

Comment: sorry bro i already using php and mysql latest version in xampp 1.8.3

Comment: This error `- SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'adminnotification_inbox' already exists";` is telling you that the database you are trying to use on app/etc/local.xml already has that table. I would try creating another new database and update the config and run the installer again. Have you used phpMyAdmin to check the target db and make sure it's empty? Most likely it's not.

Comment: ok i have solved my problem. i had to remove all files and create new database. then i reinstall magento at starting and its working fine.thanks for your replies